# Generate a .pdf starting from a .jpg

Tags: vb.net, pdf, itext

i use this code to generate an "output.pdf" starting from an "input.jpg".

The output file can be viewed without any problem on win7/win8 but has problems on winXP machines. What is wrong in my code ?

```
dw = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(InputFile)
img = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(dw, Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)
img.ScalePercent((72.0 / img.DpiX) * 100)

Dim psPageSize As New iTextSharp.text.Rectangle(0, 0, img.ScaledWidth,img.ScaledHeight)
Dim document As iTextSharp.text.Document
document = New Document(psPageSize, 0, 0, 0, 0)
Dim writer As PdfWriter
writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, New FileStream(OutputFile, FileMode.Create))
document.Open()
document.Add(img)
document.Close()
```

Comment: What are the "problems"?

Comment: Did you use the same pdf viewer (exact same version) on each client? What error do you get on xp?

Comment: And can you provide a link to the output PDF?

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with your code. The problem is on the windows xp machine, or the pdf viewer software deployed on that machine. Check the version of the pdf viewer software and upgrade it to the latest version. If it does not work, you can try to change the pdf version in your pdf like (try to findout what version is supported by the pdf viewer):

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(pdfPath);
PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, outputStream);
stamper.setPdfVersion(PdfWriter.PDF_VERSION_1_4);
stamper.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty there's nothing wrong with the code. One other possible cause (apart from what peer is saying) could be that the PDF was copied incorrectly. For instance: suppose that a file transfer protocol was used that turns all binary bytes into plain ASCII. Then you'd have a PDF with nothing but blank pages.

Unfortunately, you're not sharing the PDF and you're not telling us what is wrong with the PDF: "has problems" is very vague. Does it open? If not, what is the error message? If so, what do you see? Is the page count OK? If so, are the pages blank? If so, you have copied the file incorrectly.